# login form with https and http

Tags: http, https, security

i want to use https only for login form and after the user logs in send it to http .

login form is in page "a.php" and the action of login form is "b.php" .

my question is:

- which one should i call:  https://mysite.com/a.php or http://mysite.com/a.php
- the action should be : https://mysite.com/b.php or http://mysite.com/b.php

i mean post data is send according to form page or action page protocol??

Answer (score 0):

The page with input fields (a.php) should be on HTTP, while the page with authentication logic (b.php) should be on HTTPS.

In a.php there will be something like this:

```
<form method="post" action="https://[domain-name]/b.php">
    <input type="text" name="username" />
    <input type="password" name="password" />
    <input type="submit" value="login" />
</form>
```

Comment: While technically posting from a non-SSL to an SSL page is secure, I wouldn't bother reading the source code to check - both should be via SSL.

Comment: I concur. From a user's point of view, it's always better to see the whole website is in SSL.